# Which Bitcoin exchanges allow anyone to fund your account by a bank transfer?

Tags: exchanges, wire-transfers, money-laundering

I know MtGox doesn't allow for such transfers to prevent money laundering. Which exchanges allow for anyone to fund your account with a bank transfer (USD preferable).

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "money laundering" ?

Comment: @BitcoinMedia because it deals with practices that can be seen as money laundering?

Answer (score 3):

In the U.S. there is the ACH bank network.

[Coinbase](http://coinbase.com) is currently the only service allowing bitcoin purchases to be paid for with a transfer from a bank using the ACH network directly.

Mt. Gox and Camp BX use Dwolla which is an intermediary which allows funds to be drawn from a bank account through the ACH network.

I'm unaware of any exchanges whose policy is that it will accept a domestic or international bank wire without that coming from your own account.

Comment: How does Coinbase do ACH?

Answer (score 0):

There is [bity.com](https://bity.com) which is based in Switzerland. This is a good and reliable service. To be checked the conditions for international transfers.

Comment: What is your relation to bity? This answer may be considered spam if there is an undisclosed relation